# How can I solve an equation of this form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve for $x$,

$$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{4000-4x}-10 =0$$

Any tricks for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearrange as follows, and square both sides:-
$$\sqrt{x}-10=\sqrt{4000-4x}\\\Rightarrow x-20\sqrt{x}+100=4000-4x\\\Rightarrow 5x-20\sqrt{x}-3900=0\\\Rightarrow x-4\sqrt{x}-780=0$$
Let $y=\sqrt{x}$, so that the equation becomes a quadratic in $y$:-
$$y^2-4y-780=0$$
Can you solve for $y$, hence solve for $x$?

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Hint : shift$\sqrt{4000-4x} $ on one side and square and quadratic in $\sqrt x $
$$4000-4x=100-20\sqrt x +x$$

you can easily solve this quadratic Note that you will have to verify your solutions as you may get extra solutions